# Please provide a direct link to users' recent page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, recent-activity

I noticed somewhere last week that the envelope icon next to my user name had been replaced with a menu showing my 'recent' updates.

Well, this is a welcome improvement considering it shows me how many rep points, revisions and changes to my favourite questions I've obtained for the day, week and month.

[image: Stack Overflow earlier]
*Stack Overflow Earlier*

[image: Stack Overflow now]
*Stack Overflow Now*

While this is a good initiative, I really would like a link to the `users/recent` page so I can access it quickly instead of having to enter the url myself. I am also sure there are many out there who found the Recent Activity page quite useful despite some people complaining about it.

I did a search and realised that [a post on meta.stackoverflow.com on a similar topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope) had been removed but I found it in [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OWjGefanjxMJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope+site:meta.stackoverflow.com+what+happened+to+the+envelope+icon&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com).

I also found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446) to the question [Recent feature changes to stack exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/153038) which stated:

> - 2011-03-11: The envelope in the header next your display name linking to recent activity has been changed into a dropdown menu that opens a popup overlay with information and links. **This feature is still being refined**.

If the feature is still being refined, I think we can still have the best of both worlds by placing a link to the user's recent page on the new menu like in the picture below. The envelope icon may be removed if necessary but I strongly believe that the link should remain.

[image: My Proposal]
*My Proposed Layout*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not get too attached to `/users/recent` as it will be disappearing forever in the next week or so:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/

Answer (score 0):

If you just click on it instead of hovering, you still go to the recent activity page.  Also, notice that word `activity` at the top?  It's a link.

Comment: I see the `activity` link but it sends the user to the activity page which contains **everything** you've ever done on stackoverflow! The Recent Activity page showed only your *recent* activity. This is the difference: [Your Activity Page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159059/geekosaur?tab=activity) [Your *Recent* Activity Page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/159059).